# No links are created in the database between objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have two classes generated from edmx model that is in synch with database:

```
public partial class Activity
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Activity()
        {
            this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
        }

        public System.Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
}

public partial class Person
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Person()
        {
            this.Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
        }

        public System.Guid PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    }
```

but when I try to link objects of type `Person` with `Activity` nothing goes into the `PeopleActivities` table, it is empty. Also there is no error. There was an error regarding violation of unique primary constraint, but I commented out `People = ...` then run the program, then uncommented this code and there is no error but also no effect.

```
    Person p1 = new Person { PersonID = new Guid("F9012DB1-E639-4831-AC69-FECBE1F59F0A"), Age = 15, Name = "Roman" },
    p2 = new Person { PersonID = new Guid("73EE7313-F1C4-4312-A2F9-8224F6807A02"), Age = 23, Name = "Szczepan" },
    p3 = new Person { PersonID = new Guid("F0DF22A9-B884-4036-9678-9D0D8E1459F6"), Age = 20, Name = "Katarzyna" };
    using (StudentsActivitiesCorrect context = new StudentsActivitiesCorrect())
    {
        context.People.AddOrUpdate(person => person.PersonID, new Person[] { p1, p2, p3 });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    Activity a1 = new Activity { ActivityId = new Guid("0ADE2334-CF52-4868-9D92-D08C4B029958"), Name = "swimming", People = new HashSet<Person> { p1, p2 } },
        a2 = new Activity { ActivityId = new Guid("148E4CAF-65A8-4E26-A8BD-BB44911B2A03"), Name = "bikinga", People = new HashSet<Person> { p1, p2, p3 } },
        a3 = new Activity { ActivityId = new Guid("84B4F160-A8F6-4B4F-AE4F-0E192799122B"), Name = "boxing", People = new HashSet<Person> { p2 } };

    using (StudentsActivitiesCorrect context = new StudentsActivitiesCorrect())
    {
        context.Activities.AddOrUpdate(activity => activity.ActivityId, new Activity[] { a1, a2, a3 });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Why is it so, why those objects are not linked in the association table?

Comment: It's a many to many relationship right ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Correct.

Comment: If you use AddOrUpdate on activities before you make the link, and THEN, when you are sure there are activities AND persons in your DB, saved with the right GUID, then you associate them. Does it work ? Also, check in your DB to be sure there is a junction table created.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes this would work, but why EF can't handle the code I posted.

Comment: Well, not sure at all, but i think it's a limitation of EF, which is not able to create a multiplicity table AND it's associative table all at once. Why ? Another mystery of EF... I'm putting this question in my favorites hoping some EF genius explains it correctly